# Linea si, linea no. Leer un archivo en Python

Tags: python

tengo un problema para leer un archivo en python. El programa consiste en sacar los apellidos de un archivo `nombres.txt` y escribirlos en otros archivos según la terminación del apellido. Pude hacer que funcione pero tengo un problema. Se lee la primer linea del archivo con X apellido, la siguiente no se lee, la tercera si, y así sucesivamente. No sé cual puede ser el error.

Dejo el código:

```py
try:
    nombres = open(r"C:/Users/usuario/nombres.txt", "rt")
    armenia = open("ARMENIA.TXT", "wt") #ian
    italia = open("ITALIA.TXT", "wt") #ini
    españa = open("ESPAÑA.TXT", "wt") #ez

    for linea in nombres:

        linea = nombres.readline()
        separada = linea.split(",")
        apellido = separada[0]
        largo = len(apellido)
        if apellido[largo-3:largo] == "ian":
            armenia.write(linea)
        elif apellido[largo-3:largo] == "ini":
            italia.write(linea)
        elif apellido[largo-2:largo] == "ez":
            españa.write(linea)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No se pudo encontrar el archivo.")
except OSError:
    print("No se pudo leer el archivo.")
finally:
    try:
        nombres.close()
        armenia.close()
        italia.close()
        españa.close()
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Comment: Remueve la línea `linea = nombres.readline()`

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si bien funciona, yo preferiría quitar la ñ del código para evitar sorpresas inesperadas. Saludos